# Refreshing Pivot Tables

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am trying to write a VBA script (MS Excel) which allows me to automatically refresh Pivot Tables when the data source is refreshed. I have used the code below where the Pivot Tables are in the "Sheet1 "worksheet

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1").RefreshTable
End Sub
```

This code only works when I manually change data within the data source. However, I want the Pivot Tables to refresh when data in the data source changes due to VLOOKUP functions and not a manual input.

Does anyone perhaps have a solution for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Change `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event for `Worksheet_Change` event. That will fire everytime the data in your worksheet changes, unless it changes by formulas, which needs `Worksheet_Update` event.

Comment: @Damian I think you meant `Worksheet_Calculate` for the case of formulas recalculating.

Comment: That! thanks BigBen

Comment: @Damian and BigBen thank you for the solutions. The tables are now refreshing correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this command? I have a sharepoint site that downloads to my excel file. I added this line of the code to refresh the data:

```
Workbook.Connections("externaldata").Refresh
```